# Error al importar base de datos en phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Tengo una base de datos en phpMyAdmin la cual exporté a un archivo .sql sin ningún problema ni error.

El error viene al importar ese archivo .sql a otra base de datos me salta este error:

```
Análisis estático:

Se encontraron 1 errores durante el análisis.

Expresión desaparecida. (near "ON" at position 25)
consulta SQL: Copiar Editar Editar

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = ON;

MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

#2006 - MySQL server has gone away
```

No voy a pone de momento el archivo .sql porque son 65 Mb.

He modificado el archivo php.ini para que acepte archivos .sql de hasta 80 Mb.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola. ¿Qué tiene que ver `php.ini` aquí? Es mejor que ejecutes el `.sql` directamente en el SGBD, a no ser que estés programando una App de migración de bases de datos desde PHP. En cuanto al error, necesitas ver en qué parte exactamente ocurre, para ello no hay que poner todo el archivo `.sql`

Comment: El tamaño máximo de los archivos .sql que se pueden importar son de 40 Mb por defecto. Por otra parte al ejecutar el .sql en el SGBD me sale el mismo error.

Comment: Prueba desde una terminal con `mysql -h host -u usuario -pcontraseña  basededatos < fichero.sql`